# Instagram integration

Tags: ios, authentication, instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

Actually i just want to authenticate my app through instagram and linked in app if app is installed in my iphone.

I am using this code for instagram 
https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk

its working fine but the problem is if a user don't have Username and Password like if user created his account using FB for instagram then there is no option for login through instagram in the above tutorial. Can anybody please help me to solve the issue or is there any way to authenticate using instagram app as FB, G+ and twitter do.:(

Comment: what are you doing after login.....you want to fetch user information like name email id ???